# Get values from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have output like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [voice] => Napisy
        [quality] => 720
        [source] => YouTube
    )
[16] => Array
    (
        [voice] => Napisy
        [quality] => 720
        [source] => Mega
    )
```

And I want to get `source` to get output `[Youtube, Mega]`. Anyone know how to get this without foreach?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, show some code. Please rephrase your question, its not clear what you mean.

Comment: @Grumpy I want to get from this array "Source" and output in array [Mega, YouTube]

Comment: @Kokosadk `Without foreach`, so use `array_column()`. There are tons of duplicates on this. Search through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get source from whole array into another array using array_column.

your above array is $array

```
$source = array_column($array, 'source');
print_r($source);
```